# Probability that integer n is even given integer k is in [1,10] and n is in [1,k].

Tags: probability

An integer $k$ is picked from 1 through 10 (each is equally likely). Another
integer $n$ is then picked from 1 through $k$ (again all choices are equally
likely). What is the probability that $n$ is even?

I've recognized that I can probably pursue this problem using Bernoulli trials, however I feel as if that is but a step - not the entire solution. Specifically, letting the probability equal
$${r\choose s}p^{s}(1-p)^{s}$$
such that $s$ is the number of even integers and $r-s$ is the number of odd integers seems incorrect, as if I'm missing some steps.

Can someone push me in the right direction? I don't want the answer, just a direction to pursue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options in this situation, the first is to simply brute force the probabilities (which given you have at most a few hundred outcomes, would be fairly straightforward to write in python or R or something).

A more analytic approach would be two begin breaking the problem down, in this case you have 2 possible situations, k is even, or k is odd. If k is even than the probability of n being even is .5, and if k is odd than the probability of n being even is $({({(k-1)}/2})/k)$, which you can then sum across.

Comment: Thinking of it that way made it much simpler. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately for the sort of combinatoric/probability distribution function that you are talking about there is no general theorem to solve them all, you often are forced to try and manually explore the solution space and reduce to simpler problems by hand.

Actually, I lie, there is a general solution, it's brute force enumeration, don't ever rule it out (computers are fast), but if you want a closed form or analytic solution, it won't (usually) help.